# Django how get all invoices containing item

Tags: python, django, model

I spent over two days looking in docs and internet and cannont find solution. I have models:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
(...)

class Product(models.Model):
(...)

class InvoicedItems(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=CASCADE)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

How to get list of all invoices containing one product? I want to make search engine.

I tried to define in InvoicedItems:

```
    def get_invoices_by_article(article):
        inv_obj = InvoicedItems.objects.filter(article=article)
        inv = inv_obj.invoice
        return inv
```

But all the time I get error:
`'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'invoice'`

I know that I am close but I need your help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us the content of Invoice and Product? Is it a reason why you used a custom ImnvoicedItems class and not let Django doing it on a many to many relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this: `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'invoice'`

When you do **any** `.filter()` call it **always** returns a QuerySet Obj.. or a *fancy* list/array

Outputting in `python manage.py shell` demonstrates this:

```py
inv_obj = InvoicedItems.objects.filter(article=article_obj)
print(inv_obj)
# <QuerySet [<Article Object (1)>]>
#    ^ Not an Article Object
```

So your method will work with some minor changes (and a variable name change)

```py
def get_invoices_by_article(article):
    inv_list = InvoicedItems.objects.filter(article=article)
    inv = inv_list.first().invoice
    return inv
```

**but!** this raises 2 **major** issues:

1. What if there's no matching articles?
2. What if there's multiple?

Example Solutions:

```py
def get_invoices_by_article(article):
    inv_list = InvoicedItems.objects.filter(article=article)

    count = inv_list.count() 

    if count == 0:
        return None

    if count > 1:
        # return list of invoices
        return [i.invoice for i in inv_list]

    # implied: is 1
    # return single invoice
    return inv_list.first().invoice


# Maybe it's easier to ALWAYS return a List, so it's always a single type!
#   empty or not!
def get_invoices_by_article(article):
    return [i.invoice for i in InvoicedItems.objects.filter(article=article)]
```

---

After you figure out which path you want to take with the method, I'd recommend
making it into a Model Manager function instead.

**Current way:**

```py
invoice_item = InvoicedItems.objects.all().first()
my_return = invoice_item.get_invoices_by_article(article_obj)
```

You must *fetch* an InvoiceItem Obj **before** you can use it -> Extra work!

**Model Manager way:**

```py
my_return = InvoicedItems.objects.get_invoices_by_article(article_obj)
```

You cut out that db hit!

###### Basic Model Manager:

```py
from django.db import models

class InvoicedItemsManager(models.Manager):
  def get_invoices_by_article(article):
      return [i.invoice for i in  InvoicedItems.objects.filter(article=article)]


class InvoicedItems(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=CASCADE)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=CASCADE)

    objects = InvoicedItemsManager()
```

Simple as that! Now you can add any number of methods you want for `InvoicedItems.objects.`

---

But maybe a Model Method or a Manager Method is overkill- idk! It's up to you

Comment: Thank you for so advanced and detailed reply. It is very helpful for me and pushes my work and knowledge forward. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So first let answer your question, let's do some edit to make everything simplier:

in your model add the related_name to your fields:

```py
class InvoicedItems(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='invoiced_items')
    article = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='invoiced_items')
```

Then your query will look like this:

```py
invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(invoiced_items__article=your_article)
```

Now let's make it simplier again removing your custom class which right now is useless:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    [...]

class Invoice(models.Model):
    [...]
    products = models.ManyToManyField(to=Product, related_name='invoices')
```

And remove your model InvoicedItems.

Then your request become:

```py
invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(products=product)
```

more info on ManyToManyFields [on the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Answer (score 0):

I made it in this way:

```
    def get_invoices_by_article(article):
        inv_obj = InvoicedItems.objects.filter(article=article)
        return Invoice.objects.filter(invoiceditems__in=inv_obj)
```